# SQLite if statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sqlite, case, where-clause

I know I can use CASE statement in an SQLite query but I don't know how to built it in a WHERE clause.

Actually I have this in a long WHERE clause (this is just the part concerned by the question):

```
AND (%d >= (wines.year + wines.maturity)) AND (%d < (wines.year + wines.apogee))
```

In fact I want just that :

```
AND (%d >= (wines.year + wines.maturity))
```

**=> if wines.apogee IS NULL**

or also:

```
AND (%d >= (wines.year + wines.maturity)) AND (%d < (wines.year + wines.apogee))
```

**=> if wines.apogee IS NOT NULL**

How to use the CASE statement in this case to test if wines.apogee IS NOT NULL and add the second part of the request in this case ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hm, you can't write `... AND ((wines.apogee is NULL) OR (%d < wines.year + wines.apogee))` in SQLite?

Comment: Yes, I can write that but this doesn't solve my problem. The CL solution below works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CASE can compute any value, even a boolean value as returned by a comparison.
In SQLite, `1` is the same as "true":

```
...
AND %d >= (wines.year + wines.maturity)
AND CASE WHEN wines.apogee IS NOT NULL
         THEN %d < (wines.year + wines.apogee)
         ELSE 1
    END
...
```

The same can be done with the [ifnull() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
...
AND %d >= (wines.year + wines.maturity)
AND ifnull(%d < (wines.year + wines.apogee), 1)
...
```